# .each() $.ajax display message after complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I am needing to have a bit of text show up after my `each()` has completed all tasks within it. But it seems they are running async and the "done." displays too early. I have tried to use a delay, but it doesn't matter. And as you can see, I'm sending success and fail information to a modal for displaying which records were saved or failed. The 'done' needs to come after all `$.ajax` calls are complete.

```js
$(".QueueGrid tbody > tr").each(function () {
    dcn = "";
    if ($(this).find(".chkOtherSelected").prop("checked")) {
        claimnum = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
        dcn = $(this).find("td:eq(5)").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Approval_Inbox.aspx/SaveNote",
            data: "{dcn:'" + dcn + "',note:'" + note + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 8000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                str = "- " + dcn + "<br />";
            },
            success: function (data) {
                _savedSucess += str;
            },
            error: function () {
                _savedFail += str;
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                $("#divMassMessage").fadeIn("fast");
                $("#divMassMessage").center();
                $('#MainContent_savedSucess').html(_savedSucess);
                $('#MainContent_savedFail').html(_savedFail);
            }
        });
    }
});
$(".saveComplete").html("done.");
```

Comment: You should probably reconsider your approach and do the whole thing in one ajax request instead, its generaly a bad idea to loop ajax requests unless you are 100% certain that this is the behavior and only solution to solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX, by its very nature, is asynchronous. You can force it to be synchronous (async: false), but that will lock the browser during requests.

Alternately you can count the number of requests made, then call a function on complete every time. Count the number of completes and when it matches the number of calls, trigger your alert.

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX complete function, you may be able to check whether `this` is the last member of the array of elements you're parsing through, i.e. get a count of the number of elements in the `$().each` array and check whether the current element is equal to length of the array.  If it is, write the completed message.  If not, there are still more elements to loop through.